# How to prevent Visual Studio 2013 from re-enabling ClickOnce after building?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

This issue is quite a nuisance and is wasting valuable time. When first encountered it took some time to figure out what exactly was going on as I am presented with this message on the next compile/test run/publish attempt.

[image: clickonce subsequent compile]

Which after looking through the project entirely, as this didn't make any logical sense why I would encounter such an error since it literally JUST compiled, I noticed this happy treat :

[image: clickonce enabled itself]

... ClickOnce had re-enabled itself. So, I do my diligence, and uncheck the box, and save the project.

[image: disabled clickonce]

... and Test Run / Compile -- no problems.  ClicOnce remains off, and everything works again.  Then I publish, and there it is again (after publishing successfully), like something out of a terrible recurring dream :

[image: clickonce enabled itself]

Following are my publish settings :

[image: publish settings]

.. and publish options (from the [options] button in the above settings :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The question is, why does this keep happening, and how can I set this so that it stays OFF permanently. I am not interested in deploying this application as a ClickOnce application. This is a VB.NET WinForms project.

Comment: It does not make any sense to publish after building if you don't want a CO deployment.  Stop doing that.

Comment: Publish builds the manifest into the exe file, and sets up proper distribution of all the dependencies required.  It also strips any test data from published serialization dll.  Unless you have a better solution -- simply copying the exe doesn't handle this.